# colab truncate folder with more than 200k files

Tags: google-colaboratory

there is a maximun number of files allowed per folder when we read gdrive from colab? I create a folder from colab with more than 200k a run an "ls" command just after creation and everything is ok, but everytime i close the session and open it again (remount gdrive) the folder get truncated. can't read anymore this quantity actually not more than 20k, need to recreate/unzip the folder again. The folder contains images for training a DL model.

Answer (score 0):

update: I'm running drive.flush_and_unmount() from the notebook where i created the folder (without closing the session) and is running smoothly. From another notebook I'm controlling the qty of files inside the folder (same folder but from another notebook) and it seems that the qty is beginning to increase slowly so it look like that the solution is running drive.flush_and_unmount() to force sync to gdrive but not sure yet if after closing the session and reopening again the folder will be synced. will let you know! at least it is progress